# Filter django queryset according to condition on a field?

Tags: django

I have a model like this:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    # other fields
```

Now I am getting a dict of `id: version` like:

```
id_ver_dict = {
  # id ver 
    23: 2,
    24: 1,
    25: 3
}
```

I want to filter my queryset according to the given dict such that the version in my DB is greater than the version in the `id_ver_dict`.

How can I filter this in a single query? Is there something like this:

```
Story.objects.filter(id__in=id_ver_dict.keys(), version__gt=id_ver_dict_value)
```

P.S.: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to perform an OR on multiple ANDed queries. You need to use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to do this. You can write a list comprehension and use `functools.reduce` to do this easily:

```
import functools
import operator

id_ver_dict = {
  # id ver 
    23: 2,
    24: 1,
    25: 3
}
queryset = Story.objects.filter(functools.reduce(operator.or_, [Q(id=obj_id) & Q(version__gt=ver) for obj_id, ver in id_ver_dict.items()]))
```